# Error while updating item from datasheet view

Tags: discussion-board

There is a problem while updating any item in datasheet view of discussion list. While editing any item I get error as "you must specify non-blank value for Name". even though there is no column named 'Name' ?
I checked type conflicts as well. but there is not any.!
Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

Please check if you had set any hidden fields to non-blank. If so, you need to change the option "Require that this column contains information" of them to "no".
See the following article:

http://www.alexangas.com/blog/2009/07/the-rows-you-modified-could-not-be-saved-to-the-server-due-to-validation-errors/

Comment: I checked it. There is no hidden field on the form. I had checked this link as well...any other problem? any resolution.?

Comment: How many custom columns are there in your list and how many are mandatory?

Comment: 4 to 5 custom columns but nothing is mandatory!.